# android JNI loading mupdf (compile with NDK?)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am creating an Android Xoom application which displays a pdf in one of the Activities.

I have downloaded the mupdf source files: mupdf.c, Android.mk, Application.mk, Core.mk, and ThirdParty.mk.

I have also been to the mupdf.com web site and tried downloading various pre-compiled packages from here: http://ccxvii.net/mupdf/download/

I just switched to Android from the iPhone and have a few things to learn regarding including C code. I put the mk / c files into /jni/ in my project. I have also tried to copy the precompiled files I downloaded from the web site above in /jni/ in my project.

I have a simple class:

```
import android.graphics.*;

    public class PDFView {  
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("mupdf");
        }
    }
```

Every time I create an instance of this class the app crashes and it says "ExceptionInInitializerError" as well as "Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null" in the LogCat.

I have also downloaded the android NDK and tried to compile the source myself. I get a missing mupdf.h error and fitz.h error. Just a whole list of errors and this seems overly complicated to included a library.

I am working on a Mac in Snow Leopard. I think I'm on the right path needing to compile this as a binary, but it's been really frustrating having spent all this time learning about the NDK then it won't compile. Maybe I need an updated source.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm reading through the compiling instructions for android, it says to edit local.properties, I see no such file in this downloaded source from mupdf.com.

Comment: Let's start with your ndk-build errors. Can you show what happens when you ndk-build?

Comment: This is a bigger deal than just "loading a library" because the library has to be built for ARM and against the Android libraries. Trying to load the library will return null until you get the ndk part of this working.

Comment: Matthew, check out my post below

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your include paths properly in your Android.mk

Please post your Android.mk for more help, although in the meantime you can try to borrow from the NDK [samples](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples), which are included in your NDK folder.

Try building them as a sanity check first, then look in jni/Android.mk to see how their makefiles are setup.

The docs directory in the NDK also contains great documentation on the Android.mk file.

Honestly, it's going to be hard to use the NDK unless you are experienced in C. Knowing the ins and outs of make, gcc, and ld is of paramount importance.

**Edit** - to make this process easier, I would clone the mupdf git repository. There is actually an [Android project](http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/) there ready to be built.

Make sure you use `git` to do the clone, as you want to have all of the necessary files. The readme has simple instructions on building. It seems like getting this working first and tweaking it from there might be a more reliable development path for you.

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

MUPDF_ROOT := ..

include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/Core.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/ThirdParty.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
 $(MUPDF_ROOT)/draw \
 $(MUPDF_ROOT)/fitz \
 $(MUPDF_ROOT)/mupdf
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=
LOCAL_MODULE    := mupdf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mupdf.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mupdfcore mupdfthirdparty

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: So I have gotten pretty far. I read through Thirdparty.mk and noticed that the directories they specify don't include the version numbers like the folders I downloaded. So I renamed the folder and am able to get to the point where it now says "No rule to make target". I am trying to figure this out, the last line of the Core.mk is $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY). There has to be another path some place that needs to be updated for the make file or something.

Comment: God ... now I'm getting stuff like "pdf_crypt.c:364: undefined reference to `fz_sha256init'". I just finished editing the source for a type redefinition. Why is this distributed with bugs like this? Wouldn't they run a test build? Or only "worthy" developers allowed to use this code if they can spend 3 hours debugging it.

Comment: The Android project link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to build mupdf library for android.
I concur with Paul, I had to do a little bit of tinkering to get it to work. You should be able to fix these errors with minor changes. What you should concentrate on, is making sure the paths to all those different thirdparty source folders are present and correct.